# Overage Customer Portal Manager Custom licenses and approval processes

Tags: approval-process, customer-portal

Our org has Overage Authenticated Website(OAW) licenses and Overage Customer Portal Manager Custom(OCPMC) Licenses. The people with OAW licenses should login to their portal and should be able to submit a form(record) using a VF Page. Once the record is submitted the people with OCPMC license should be able to approve the record. Is it possible to get approvals for the submitted records. Can it be done by the standard approval process. If yes how and what limitations can we expect?

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at the following documentation: [Help: Authenticated Website User Licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_platformportal.htm&type=0), [Customer Portal Implementation Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/206/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_customer_portal_implementation_guide.pdf), [Help: Customer Portal—Enterprise Administration User Licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_customerportal_enterpriseadmin.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=206.12) and [Help: Communities User Licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=206.12).

First, like `customer community` users, `portal users` do not have a `Role`. Instead, they only have a `Profile`. In order to use the standard approval process, one needs to be able to determine who one's "request approver" is. Typically, that would be done by determining who the user's supervisor is. More specifically, the mechanism that Salesforce uses is the `User Role`.

Since portal users don't have a Role assigned to them, Salesforce wouldn't be able to determine who should be the approver. That being said, in customer communities, users can **submit** items for approval, but cannot approve them. I could not find any documentation to indicate that approval workflow was supported for this particular license when submitting items for standard approval workflow.

Assuming an item *could* be submitted, the issue you'd still face is that your `Overage Customer Portal Manager` will also not have a `Role` and would not be able to act as the "approver" unless also assigned a Salesforce User license. Customer community workflow approvals are only made by users who have Salesforce licenses.

Based on the above, it's my conclusion that you'll need to create your own approval form/object and workflow to process them between your two different types of users.